# Transition to index route via back button is very slow with ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, single-page-application

I've got 2 routes. An "index" route which shows a list of models and a "show" routes that you navigate to by clicking on one of the models in the list and shows more details about that model. When transitioning from the index route to the show route everything is nice and fast but then when going back to the index route by clicking the back button it can take sometimes up to 10+ seconds to complete.

The odd thing is that if I have a link in the show routes template that links directly to the index route the transition is much much faster. Any idea whats going on?

Below is the related code:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('notebooks');
  this.resource('notebook', { path: '/notebooks/:notebook_id' });
});

App.NotebooksRoute = Ember.Route.extend(Ember.SimpleAuth.AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('notebook');
  },

  setupController: function(controller, notebooks) {
    controller.set('content', notebooks);
  }
});

App.NotebookRoute = Ember.Route.extend(Ember.SimpleAuth.AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('notebook', params.notebook_id);
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
    controller.set('pages', model.get('pages'));
  }
});
```

Comment: If you pause it where is the code executing?

Comment: this might sound stupid, can u try setting this.resource('notebooks', {path: {'/'}); ?

Comment: @kingpin2k if I pause it the code is executing at line 6428 in ember.js in a function called "updateLaterTimer"

Comment: @Yman changing the path does nothing.